# How can I link multiple p5 JS projects to the same index.html?

Tags: javascript, html, object, libraries, p5.js

I have a p5 JavaScript project folder containing many JavaScript documents/projects. In order to view my code in a browser obviously I just run the linked HTML document.

My problem is that if I were to link multiple p5 JavaScript projects in my index.html I only get the last linked JavaScript project.

I could simply make a separate HTML document for each project however that would double the number of documents in my project folder and potentially create a lot of unnecessary work for myself.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>JS learnings</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/p5/lib/p5.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/p5/lib/addons/p5.dom.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/p5/lib/addons/p5.sound.js"></script>
    <script src="./classes.js"></script>;
    <script src="./function-picture.js"></script>;
    <script src="./ifs-within-ifs.js"></script>;
    <script src="./while-and-for-loops.js"></script>;
    <script src="./Boolean.js"></script>;
    <script src="./object-var.js"></script>;
    <script src="./move.js"></script>;
  </body>
</html>
```

This code simply displays ./move.js in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to support multiple sketches in one window, you're going to need to use **instance mode**.

By default, P5.js uses the global namespace for its variables and functions. So every time you define a `setup()` or `draw()` function, you're overwriting any previous values. That's why you only see the last sketch you load.

To get around this, you can use **instance mode** to encapsulate each sketch in a non-global scope. You can read more about instance mode [here](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode), but here's an example:

```
var s = function( sketch ) {

  var x = 100; 
  var y = 100;

  sketch.setup = function() {
    sketch.createCanvas(200, 200);
  };

  sketch.draw = function() {
    sketch.background(0);
    sketch.fill(255);
    sketch.rect(x,y,50,50);
  };
};

var myp5 = new p5(s);
```

You would want to create a new `p5` instance for each sketch.

Comment: Great answer. I suppose there's no easy way to have one sketch in the window at a time while still achieving this?

Comment: @Maximilian It depends on what you mean by easy. For example you could have a button that loads the next sketch using the above syntax. That would be relatively straightforward, but of course more complicated than P5's default simplified syntax.